# How can I make an alias expand to a list of recipients returned by a command?

Tags: email, freebsd, exim, alias

I have an rarely used `/etc/aliases` entry

```
vmailusers: :include:/usr/local/etc/vmailusers
```

The `/usr/local/etc/vmailusers` file is generated by a cronjob executing

```
ls /home/vmail | grep -v lists > /usr/locale/etc/vmailusers
chmod 0640 /usr/local/etc/vmailusers
chmod mailnull:mail /usr/local/etc/vmailusers
```

Is there a way to avoid having to run a cron job but rather execute the `ls` command in the very moment the `vmailusers` alias is used?

Comment: Moin Frerich, It seems to be possible with sendmail, there is the same question for sendmail on serverfault. But i  have no idea if it works the same in exim.

Comment: @arved: Hello there, long time no see :-) I'll have a look at the sendmail answer and see whether it applies to exim as well.

Answer (score 0):

With exim you need no `/etc/aliases` anymore.
All that you have to do - is to define redirect router like that:

```
vmail_aliases:
        driver          = redirect
        data            = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/usr/local/etc/vmailusers}}
        file_transport  = address_file
        pipe_transport  = address_pipe
```

Refer to the exim spec chapter 9.3 describing lookup in the files by lsearch. At least, lsearch'ed files have the same syntax as `/etc/aliases` so you haven't mess with converting your current /usr/local/etc/vmailusers to some freaky format. Don't forget to place that router **before** any accepting router in your config.

Exim lookup for given key each time the message is processed, so all your changes become actual just when you save your aliases file.